# AWK passing loop variables

Tags: variables, awk

So I have this file containing timestamps.

```
cat file
2022/01/27-00:47:05;2022/01/27-00:47:05;
2022/01/27-00:47:06;2022/01/27-00:47:06;
2022/01/27-00:48:59;2022/01/27-00:48:59;
2022/01/27-01:38:06;2022/01/27-01:38:06;
2022/01/27-01:45:17;2022/01/27-01:45:17;
2022/01/27-01:47:46;2022/01/27-01:47:47;
<bunch of lines>
2022/01/27-15:00:01;2022/01/27-15:00:01;
2022/01/27-15:00:05;2022/01/27-15:00:05;
2022/01/27-15:00:06;2022/01/27-15:00:06;
```

And I was trying to create a for loop to isolate all those lines whose first field is 2022/01/27-**hour**:.

So far, this is what I've come up with, but it's not working:

```
for var in {00..23}
do
awk -F ';' -v var="$var" '$1 ~2022/01/27-var"' file > $var.txt
done
```

I’m getting no output at all.

And what trying to accomplish is getting 24 files, whose content is hourly timestamps.

00.txt: all lines whose first field matches 2022-01-27-**00**

01.txt: all lines whose first field matches 2022-01-27-**01**

…/…

23.txt: all lines whose first field matches 2022-01-27-**23**

I'm clearly missing something, but I don't know what, because this other thing seems to work just fine.

```
for kk in {00..23}
do
echo | awk -v kk="$kk" '{print kk}'
done
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
```

I must be passing the variable the wrong way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, exactly: I’m getting no output at all. 

The expected output should be all those lines whose first field contains 2022/01/27-$var: 2022/01/27-00, 2022/01/27-01 as per the loop substitution.

Comment: Are there guaranteed to be entries in your input file for each hour of the target day? If not should an empty output file for that hour be created or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all lines start with a datetime stamp like `YYYY/MM/DD-HH:`
- datetime stamps may cover multiple days but output files are still based simply on `HH` (ie, each `HH.txt` file could contain data from different days)

One `GNU awk` idea that eliminates the need for the `bash` loop:

```
awk -F'[-:]' '{print $0 > $2".txt"}' file
```

**NOTES:**

- `-F'[-:]` - define two input field delimiters (`-` and `:`)
- use field #2 as the prefix for the name of the output file
- we're talking about a max of 24 output files so there should be no issues of maxing out the number of open file descriptors

For the given sample input (sans the line `<bunch of lines>`) this generates:

```
$ for fname in {00..23}.txt; do [[ -f "${fname}" ]] && echo "########### $fname" && cat $fname; done
########### 00.txt
2022/01/27-00:47:05;2022/01/27-00:47:05;
2022/01/27-00:47:06;2022/01/27-00:47:06;
2022/01/27-00:48:59;2022/01/27-00:48:59;
########### 01.txt
2022/01/27-01:38:06;2022/01/27-01:38:06;
2022/01/27-01:45:17;2022/01/27-01:45:17;
2022/01/27-01:47:46;2022/01/27-01:47:47;
########### 15.txt
2022/01/27-15:00:01;2022/01/27-15:00:01;
2022/01/27-15:00:05;2022/01/27-15:00:05;
2022/01/27-15:00:06;2022/01/27-15:00:06;
```

Comment: `print $0 > $2".txt"` is relying on undefined behavior (no parens around an expression on the right side of input/output redirection) and so will produce a syntax error in some awks. It'll also cause a "too many open files" error in some awks after crossing a threshold which I've seen hit in the 15-20 output files range. It'll do what you want in GNU awk though so you could just say that.

Comment: It's also assuming that there are always entries for a given hour because if there weren't then it woudn't create an output file for that hour, unlike the OPs shell loop version.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `match` explicitly instead of `~`. eg:

```
awk 'match($1,"2022/01/27-" var )' var=00 FS=\; input
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following `awk` program. This program is sorting your Input_file based on 1st field and then passing its output to `awk` program as an input. In `awk` program its making `-` and `:` as field separators for each line. Then its checking if 1st field of line is `2022/01/27` AND 2nd field is 2 digits then printing whole line to 2nd field(which is hours value). Its also taking care of closing output file in backend to avoid "too many opened files" error.

```
sort -s -t';' -k1 Input_file | 
awk -F'[-:]' '
$1=="2022/01/27" && $2~/^[0-9]{2}$/ {
  outFile = $2 ".txt"
  if ( prev != outFile ) {
    close(prev)
    prev = outFile
  }
  print > outFile
}
'
```